What should I do to load img at React?
WebSite can not load Images.
in react.js, upload image to firebase storage.
then, I want to load img like:
const imagelist = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState( ... );
    ...
    return <ul>
        {list.map(v => {
            return(<li key={v.id}>
                ...
                <img loading='lazy' alt='thumbnail' src={v.imageUrl}></img>
            </li>
        })}
    </ul>
}

but, WebSite can not load imgs

The status code of the response is 200.
The image from the Sources tab in DevTools is:

This image has 0 Byte!
On WebSite, The list of images is shown as follows:

How do I fix it??????
I checked:

Firebase SDK configuration is correct
Image uploaded successfully
The image path is correct
The image path was set to the src property of the  tag
In Firebase Storage, read rule is always true.
The width and height of  are specified as 100px.
The CORS policy is as follows:

[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]

